# DD: error writing - No space left on device

Tags: 18.04, usb, dd, clone

I have two SanDisk Extreme Pro USB sticks/disks which are exactly 128,000,000,000 bytes each (about 119GiB) and have been using the dd command regularly to clone one disk from the other (I've succeeded on ten previous attempts). I'm now getting a classic dd error as follows:

> dd: error writing '/dev/sdd ': No space left on device

I am using count and block size (bs) arguments to prevent errors associated with unlimited cloning. I've copied output from the terminal below to elaborate for anyone who is able to help. It first shows output from fdisk and an unmounting operation.

---------Terminal Output----------

```
sudo fdisk -l

[Note: I've ommitted some of the output of this command, keeping relevant bits.]

Disk /dev/sda: 14.6 GiB, 15682240512 bytes, 30629376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe735b15f

Device    Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *    2048 30629375 30627328 14.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/sdc: 119.3 GiB, 128043712512 bytes, 250085376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BC24B30C-D71B-4595-82F1-F4ED27740828

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1  64825344 238905343 174080000  83G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2      2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc3      4096    503807    499712  244M EFI System
/dev/sdc4    503808  4610047  4106240    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdc5    4610048  64825343  60215296 28.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdc6  238905344 249759743  10854400  5.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 119.3 GiB, 128043712512 bytes, 250085376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BC24B30C-D71B-4595-82F1-F4ED27740828

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1  64825344 238905343 174080000  83G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd2      2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdd3      4096    503807    499712  244M EFI System
/dev/sdd4    503808  4610047  4106240    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd5    4610048  64825343  60215296 28.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd6  238905344 249759743  10854400  5.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for n in /dev/sdc* ; do umount $n ; done
umount: /dev/sdc: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdc1: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdc2: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdc3: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdc4: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdc5: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdc6: not mounted.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd  bs=1000000 count=128000 conv=sync,noerror status=progress
7988000000 bytes (8.0 GB, 7.4 GiB) copied, 28 s, 285 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdd ': No space left on device
8241+0 records in
8240+0 records out
8240062464 bytes (8.2 GB, 7.7 GiB) copied, 29.0572 s, 284 MB/s
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that once I corrected filesystem errors on my USB stick, the dd command would run without problems. The filesystem errors were corrected using the e2fsck command (fsck will do).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your result :-) Interesting: I must admit, that I don't understand why fixing the file system would help cloning. Maybe internal re-ordering of the link between logical and physical memory cells in the USB stick replaced come bad memory cell with a fresh one and made the cloning successful?